# A lot of data that need to be continuously passed to the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm currently building a community with Laravel.

In my project, All view files extends `layouts.master`.

By default, 8 pieces of data are received from `layouts.master`.

It's really hard to copy-paste the same operation in the model every time i write new logic and create a method on the controller.

It's getting harder to focus on the essentials.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Check view composers

Comment: Please share some code which you've done and what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste the same code over and over again, you are totally go in the wrong direction.

If you always use the same code over and over again just create a method for that one, or maybe a library where you can get call the same code over and over again in a lot of different location